flask url not showing in command line on importing zowe modules
I'm working on a Flask application which uses Zowe SDK to submit mainframe batch job & download o/p dataset.
I'm importing below modules.
from zowe.zos_jobs_for_zowe_sdk import Jobs
from zowe.zos_files_for_zowe_sdk.datasets import Datasets

Job gets submitted and file downloaded successfully. There is no issue with the application.
But invoking the application (python file) from command line never shows the expected default URL as below which usually comes up for any flask app.

Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000

I'm able to infer that above mentioned zowe modules is interfering and hence the problem as when I comment out the import statements the url does show up.
Any directions where lies the problem ? Or how can I troubleshoot to fix the issue.
I badly need a fix as this application will mostly be run from command line.
